# SQL Server average of last three days

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that I keep track of failure rates on a daily basis.  I need to get the average, last 3 days, of each column in order to make adjustments.  My stored procedure is -

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[dfc_sp_average_loan_failure]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT   TOP(3)
             AVG(usOnlineRate)  AS usOnlineAverage
            ,AVG(usRetailRate)  AS usRetailAverage
            ,AVG(cnOnlineRate)  AS cnOnlineAverage
            ,AVG(cnRetailRate)  AS cnRetailAverage

    FROM dfc_LoanRateRecords
END
```

I have four records in the table, but it keeps giving me the average of the first three not the last three.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need

```
WHERE your_date BETWEEN dateadd(day, -3, maximum_date) and maximum_date
```

Not `TOP(3)` - this would give you exactly 3 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an order by to the end of your query.

```
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This would give the last three dates.

Comment: That's correct only if he have exactly 1 row for each date.

Comment: You can replace `date` with whatever you want to order by (loan number, id, ect.)   When you use `TOP()` in SQL, you should always include a `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Ingaz This is true.  This will only work if you have one row per day